# find the value of a substring between two constants and after a constant

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string with the value Y2014M1D2. if I wanted to get a substring of this value with only the numbers between M and D, i.e "1" and another one with only the value after D i.e "2". How can I do this? Before I was using substings with offsets and lengths in the parameters like this:

```
var str = 12345;
var sub = str.substr(2,1);
```

which was OK but now the strings are all different lengths, so this is no longer effective. I think I need to use the replace command now. Can anyone help me out? Thank you.

Comment: I'd say: Split using regex "not a number" and join by '-' character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a simple [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```
var matches = 'Y2014M1D2'.match(/Y(\d+)M(\d+)D(\d+)/);
var y = matches[1];
var m = matches[2];
var d = matches[3];
```